# How to create file chooser with camera option in android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera, filechooser

I want to implement file chooser with camera option.When we select `Camera` images should be captured and the path of captured image should displayed on textview.and file chooser should be with `pdf`,`word`,`png` and `jpeg` validation. I tired fileChhoser only but I dont Understand how to implement camera option in that.

The code i have used

```
  ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> sActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @SuppressLint("Range")
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    Intent data1 = result.getData();
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Uri uri1 = data1.getData();
                    String uriString = uri.toString();
                    String uriString1 = uri1.toString();
                    File myFile = new File(uriString1);
                    String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    String displayName = null;
                    String displayName1= null;
                    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                //   displayName1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                Log.i("displayname",""+displayName);
                                fileidname.setText(displayName);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                        displayName = myFile.getName();
                        //  displayName1= myFile.getName();
                        Log.i("displayname1",""+displayName);
                        fileidname.setText(displayName);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
);


ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> sActivityResultLauncher1 = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @SuppressLint("Range")
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    //Intent data = result.getData();
                    Intent data1 = result.getData();
                    // Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Uri uri1 = data1.getData();
                    // String uriString = uri.toString();
                    String uriString1 = uri1.toString();
                    File myFile = new File(uriString1);
                    String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    String displayName = null;
                    String displayName1= null;

                    if (uriString1.startsWith("content://")) {
                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try {
                            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri1, null, null, null, null);
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                // displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                displayName1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                Log.i("displayname",""+displayName);
                                fileidname1.setText(displayName1);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } else if (uriString1.startsWith("file://")) {
                        //displayName = myFile.getName();
                        displayName1= myFile.getName();
                        Log.i("displayname1",""+displayName);
                        fileidname1.setText(displayName1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
);
public void OpenfileDialog(View view) {

    Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    data.setType("*/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*","application/pdf"};
    data.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,mimeTypes);
    data = Intent.createChooser(data,"Choose a file");
    sActivityResultLauncher.launch(data);
}

public void OpenfileDialog1(View view) {

    Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    data.setType("*/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*","application/pdf"};
    data.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,mimeTypes);
    data = Intent.createChooser(data,"Choose a file");
    sActivityResultLauncher1.launch(data);
}
```

Comment: File choosers have no camera option. Its unclear what you have in mind.

Comment: @blackaps i want two options in  popup 1-Camera option & 2- File

Comment: You can use a double intent for that. Or build your own 'popup'. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Pure File-chooser does not invoke camera. It is a bit complicated but you will need to sandwich a camera intent inside.